# Unknown namespace for jpa - ServiceMix

Tags: java, rest, osgi, cxf, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to follow a simple tutorial, exposing a simple CRUD interface as a REST service using blueprint
[github link to tutorial code](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/tasklist-service/src/main/java/net/lr/tasklist/service/impl/TaskServiceRest.java)

when deployed to serviceMix, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown namespace for jpa: http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd
```

I have no idea why, I installed the same `features` as the tutorial [features](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/features/src/main/resources/features.xml)

And I have the same `maven dependencies` [dependencies](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/tasklist-service/pom.xml)

My `bundle:list` gives the following [list of bundles](http://pastebin.com/raw/ZA1XUhhS)

The `bundles` with `state:failure` are  failing because of this problem

Any ideas ?

## Update 1 :

content of `blueprint` [blueprint](http://pastebin.com/raw/u6MZMPFT)

i'm also using `blueprint-maven-plugin` which generates the following [generated blueprint](http://pastebin.com/raw/7eAsB775)

## Update 2 :

as suggested by Christian Schneider, installing aries-jpa 2.5.0 solved the problem, one weird thing happened though :
before, when I had the  2.3.0 version installed, I had the following `aries` related bundles installed :

```
254 | Active  |  80 | 2.3.0 | Apache Aries JPA Container API
255 | Active  |  80 | 2.3.0 | Apache Aries JPA blueprint
256 | Active  |  80 | 2.3.0 | Apache Aries JPA container
257 | Active  |  80 | 2.3.0 | Apache Aries JPA support
```

now that I have the 2.5.0, those bundles are no longer shown when doing `bundle:list`

`feature:list` shows the following

```
jpa| 2.5.0|| Started| aries-jpa-2.5.0| OSGi Persistence Container
```

So the question is, should I be concerned that those bundles are no longer shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the blueprint content. I was on the wrong track with my first answer.

The reason for the error is [the issue ARIES-1600 in aries jpa](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1600). The issue is fixed in Aries JPA 2.5.0. You can use it by adding this feature repo url to your feature:

```
mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/jpa-features/2.5.0/xml/features
```

If you install from command line you can install it using:

feature:repo-add aries-jpa 2.5.0

Comment: thank you, this solved the problem, I still have a related question (Update 2)

Comment: The number of installed bundles should not be different between aries jpa 2.5.0 and 2.3.0. When I do a la -s | grep jpa I see the usual 4 bundles.

Comment: Doing la -s | grep jpa does show the usual bundles, is it different from bundle:list ?

Comment: Yes. bundle:list only shows bundles with a high start level. You can also use  bundle:list -t 0